# *ngIf for html attribute in Angular2

Tags: angular

```
<ion-navbar  hideBackButton >
  <ion-title> </ion-title>
  ...
  ...
```

I want `hideBackButton` to be there conditionally and I don't want to repeat the whole ion-navbar element with *ngIf.
Is it possible to to apply *ngIf for hideBackButton attribute?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can leverage interpolation:

```
<ion-navbar [attr.hideBackButton]="someExpression">
  <ion-title> </ion-title>
  ...
...
```

If `someExpression` is null the attribute won't be present and if `someExpression` is an empty string, the attribute will be there. Here is a sample:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div [attr.hideBackButton]="someExpression">
      Test
    </div>
    <div (click)="toggleAttribute()">Toggle</div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() {
    this.someExpression = null;
  }

  toggleAttribute() {
    if (this.someExpression==null) {
      this.someExpression = '';
    } else {
      this.someExpression = null;
    }
  }
}
```

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/LL012UVBZ421iPX4H59p?p=preview

Comment: initially there was a problem with the initialization of plunker link. but now its works well.

Comment: Euh yes, my sample plunkr works ;-) What do you mean by "does example work"?

Answer (score 46):

You have to provide `null` to boolean values for them to get removed,

```ts
<ion-navbar [attr.hideBackButton]="someExpression ? true : null">
```

otherwise angular creates

```ts
<ion-navbar hideBackButton="false">
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm resolving this problem using this approach:

```html
<button class="btn"
          aria-expanded="false"

          #btnId
          (click)="log(btnId.attributes.getNamedItem('aria-expanded')?.value)"
          >

    Button click
</button>
```